# How can I accept the default commit message in GitHub?

Tags: git, github

Many times I go to my repos and I want to make a small typo change via my browser. When I do this small change there is a *suggested commit message*.

How do I accept this suggested commit message when using my browser?

Like so:[image]

Comment: Just hit the Commit changes button? Did you even _try_ it? — And how exactly is this a _programming_ question?

Comment: @matt, questions involving "software tools commonly used by programmers" are explicitly [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: I do agree that the question is a bit confusing, though. What's the specific problem?

Comment: Are you asking how to use that default commit message?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Hit the Commit changes button.

Comment: But this is what I said in my first comment. And it's still not a programming problem (in my view). Couldn't we just delete the question and ease the bandwidth?